# Using database file built by another app

Tags: java, android

So I am working on an app that looks up data in a database. To populate the database, I built an app that read a text and added the data to that database. Now I want to use the populated database for another app that will look for the data required by the user and the database. Where is the database file saved on the phone and how can I add it to another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider using ContenProvider.
Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process
see this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html